# Axis 1.4 webservice client with WS-Security

Tags: java, web-services, axis, keystore, ws-security

i'm trying to write a webservice client using Apache Axis 1.4. Webservice is using WS-Security and after several attempts i need some help. I wrote following code:

```
        sbinary.WSHttpBinding_IServiceStub stub;
        stub = (sbinary.WSHttpBinding_IServiceStub)new sbinary.ServiceLocator().getWSHttpBinding_IService();

        stub._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.CHECK_MUST_UNDERSTAND, Boolean.FALSE);
        stub._setProperty(Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, serviceUsername);
        stub._setProperty(Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, servicePassword);
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // take action
        }
        addWsSecurityHeader(stub, serviceUsername, servicePassword);
        stub.pingDatabase();`
```

I've override certificate validation, because server has an insecure (self-signed) certificate that I'm unable to validate. After runnig this code i've got response: `the security context token is expired or is not valid`. I also tried to user following code

```
    protected void addWsSecurityHeader(org.apache.axis.client.Stub binding, String wsUser, String wsPass) throws SOAPException {

    // Create the top-level WS-Security SOAP header XML name.
    QName headerName = new QName(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security");
    SOAPHeaderElement header = new SOAPHeaderElement(headerName);
    //  no intermediate actors are involved.
    header.setActor(null);
    // not important, "wsse" is standard
    header.setPrefix("wsse");
    header.setMustUnderstand(true);

     //Add the UsernameToken element to the WS-Security header
    SOAPElement utElem = header.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
    SOAPElement userNameElem = utElem.addChildElement(wsUser);
    userNameElem.setValue(wsUser);
    SOAPElement passwordElem = utElem.addChildElement(wsPass);
    passwordElem.setValue(wsPass);

    // Finally, attach the header to the binding.
    binding.setHeader(header);
}
```

but then i've got error: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.`
If you can point me to a good tutorial it would be helpful, thanks (Sorry for formatting).